# Cannot create a DbSet for 'Model' because this type is not included in the model for the context

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I do a Generic and using DI

so I create a empty class

```
public class DBRepo
{ 
}
```

and my model class to inheriting class DBRepo

```
public partial class UserAccount : DBRepo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Account { get; set; }
   public string Pwd { get; set; }
}
```

then this is a Interface to do CRUD

```
    public interface IDBAction<TEntity> where TEntity : class,new()
    {   
      void UpdateData(TEntity _entity);
      void GetAllData(TEntity _entity);
    }
public class DBService<TEntity> : IDBAction<TEntity> where TEntity : class,new()
{
    private readonly CoreContext _db;
    public DBService(CoreContext _db)
    {
        this._db = _db;
    }
    public void UpdateData(TEntity _entity)
    {
        this._db.Set<TEntity>().UpdateRange(_entity);
        this._db.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void GetAllData(TEntity _entity)
    {
        var x = this._db.Set<TEntity>().Select(o => o).ToList();
    }
}
```

And I Dependency Injection Service Provider in constructor

```
this.DBProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddScoped<IDBAction<DBRepo>, DBService<DBRepo>>()
    .AddScoped<DBContext>()
    .AddDbContext<CoreContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString))
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

last step I Get Services

```
DBProvider.GetService<IDBAction<DBRepo>>().GetAllData(new UserAccount());
```

I will get a error message same with title

or I change to

```
DBProvider.GetService<IDBAction<UserAccount>>().GetAllData(new UserAccount());
```

I'll get other message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

but the void UpdateData() is can work,
so how to fix GetAllData() problem?

Answer (score 7):

The error simply is because the class you're using here `UserAccount` has apparently not been added to your context, `CoreContext`. There should be a property there like:

```
public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
```

Regardless of whether you end up using the generic `Set<T>` accessor, you still must defined a `DbSet` for the entity on your context.

That said, you should absolutely not be creating your own service collection inside your repo. Register your context and your repo with the main service collection in Startup.cs and then simply inject your repo where you need it. The DI framework will take care of instantiating it with your context, as long as you have a constructor that takes your context (which you seem to).

And *that* said, you should ditch the repo entirely. It still requires a dependency on Entity Framework and doesn't do anything but proxy to Entity Framework methods. This is just an extra thing you have to maintain and test with no added benefit.

Comment: so how to do in Startup.cs can you show me a easy sample?

Comment: This is annoying. So, one will have to add a new property for each POCO object he wants to map from the DB results? I use SPs and `_dbContext.Set<MyPOCO>().FromSql("....")`to fetch results and this solution will fill my DB context with properties! I have found another post saying that you could do the same from your Startup.cs EF setup: `uilder.Entity<MyPOCO>().HasKey(p => new { p.Prop1, p.Prop2 });`. But this seems too much for a simple de-serialization operation too. Isn't there any other alternative?

Comment: How is it annoying? This is how things work. The DbContext is the unit of work, and as such, it needs the repositories (i.e. each DbSet) added to it. More abstractly, how is the context supposed to know about your entities unless you tell it explicitly. Entities at the end of the day are just POCOs, so even if EF wanted to help you out here, it could do nothing but add every single class that existed, which would obviously not be desirable.

Comment: Also, you don't *have* to use EF. If all you're dealing with is stored procedures, then maybe a micro ORM like Dapper is a better fit.

Comment: A few years later. But I think this is a very bad answer, Chris Pratt. You've helped a lot of people too. EF core 6 should allow creating stored procs from expression trees during EF migrations. Model Builder should allow quickly switching between similar stored procs so you can optimize. There is some phenomenal potential stepping through the source code over the years. EF could have been written extensible. But it chose to not follow SOLID principles. Hence, frustrated customers.